# AngularJS $scope not updating on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sometimes i'm struggling to understand the angular scope, and its inheritance, and today seems to be one of those days...

Basically i just want to disable a button when its pressed, im using ng-click and ng-disable for this. Is there some other method that needs to be used for this kind of function? The ng-docs uses a value that is bound to the ng-disabled, but in my case i would want to simply use one element only.

Heres the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lpttdDDUP3gdhRUeZ8Wk?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `ng-disabled`, you're already writing in Angular, so remove the `{{}}` and just make it `isdisabled`. Be sure to toggle that in your function then.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CGzvFjLfkvPV2cuOfb2g?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Could you further elaborate why theres no need for the curly-braces? Is it because of the ng-disabled directive?

Comment: `ng-*` are angular directives, therefore when writing inside them, you're already writing in Angular, no need to use the `{{}}`. Hence your `ng-click='function()` isn't `ng-click="{{function()}}"`